# ggplot color based on partial match variable name

Tags: r

If I have a data frame like below, how could I use ggplot, with "variables" as the faceting variable, to make the "ABC X1" + "ABC X2" and "DEF X1" + "DEF X2" plot be the same color but on different plots? These will be line plots and I will be using facet_wrap is that helps with the solution.

```
x <- c("ABC X1", "ABC X2", "DEF X1", "DEF X2", "ABC X1", "ABC X2", "DEF X1", "DEF X2")
y <- c(6, 23, 14, 19, 77, 34, 11, 109)
df1 <- melt(data.frame(variables = x, values = y), id=c("variables"))
```

Edit: Included some values for the variables.
Edit: The string in "variables" will not always be the same size as the example given, but the string before X1 and X2 for the matching pairs will always be the same (i.e. "ABC X1" and "ABC X2" could be "ABCDEF X1" and "ABCDEF X2").

Comment: Could you please include the complete data frame with the variable(s) and values you want to plot as lines, see [mre] for guidance on producing a reproducible question. You can paste the complete data frame into the question using `dput(df1)`

Comment: Edited with some values in data frame.

Comment: I'm not sure you have enough data to plot lines?. Do you want to facet_wrap on each of the x values? i.e. four panels based on  "ABC X1" , "ABC X2",  "DEF X1" , "DEF X2" or on the grouped x values i.e. 2 panels based on  "ABC X1" + "ABC X2" and "DEF X1" + "DEF X2"?

Comment: Sorry about that. See my edit above. For the example, there should be 4 total panels faceted on "variables"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `str_extract` (package `stringr`) to get the first parts:

```r
x <- c("ABC X1", "ABC X2", "DEF X1", "DEF X2")
y <- c(6, 23, 14, 19)
df1 <- data.frame(variables = x, values = y)

ggplot(df1, aes(x=variables, y=values, color=str_extract(variables, ".*(?=\\bX\\d+)")))  +
  geom_point() + 
  labs(color = "Variables")
```

I'm looking for a white space `\\b`, followed by an `X`, followed by one or more digits `\\d+`. Then I take everything in front of this to create the color group.

Comment: Is there a better solution to make it more universal and not rely on knowing the string length in "variables"?

Comment: Do you have any information on the structure of your strings in `variables`?

Comment: The string will always be in the form of "[Insert User-defined String Here] X1/2" For example, metadata file might contain c("Male_Height X1", "Male_Height X2", "Female_Width X1", "Female_Width X2", ...) and another might contain c("Growth_Rate X1", "Growth Rate X2", "White_Chalk X1", "White_Chalk X2",...). So, the total length of the string will change, but each string will always end up with X1 or X2.

Comment: Changed my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help mate!